# Can you can homebrew?

Tags: bottle-conditioning

Does anyone know of a company that sells canning equipment that's not outrageously expensive? I'd love to be able to can my homebrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything I've found is pretty expensive. [Cask.com](http://www.cask.com) advertises small-scale manual beer-canning equipment that's presumably pretty cheap, but I can't find their on-line store. Your local U-Brew might have a canning machine that they'll let you use.